# Kafka compaction on a topic stopped

Tags: apache-kafka

I have multiple Kafka topics on which compaction is enabled. On all the topics compaction is happening fine but on one topic I am facing below issue.

The compaction happened until a point of time, after that it never happened. When I went through log cleaner logs there weren't any exceptions or logs telling me the potential reason why compaction stopped.

I am wondering what could be the reason for this behavior. How do i force my compaction to happen?
Any sort of advice would be helpful.

Comment: How do you know compaction has stopped?

Comment: My disk size is growing more than it should, and from the logs I could see compaction is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happen because the compacting thread (log cleaner) crashed. Next step in troubleshooting is to find the reason it crashed and fix it. I'd search the main server logs for exceptions.

Log cleaner became a lot more stable over time, so if you are running versions older than 2.0, I recommend upgrading.

Comment: I am running version above 2, i have gone through all the server logs, nothing regarding any exceptions is found. Are the log cleaner threads separate for every topic? Could i force compact somehow?

Comment: All the new index, timestamp index files are getting created for new segments, but the process after that compaction is not happening.

Comment: @user306 `log-cleaner.log` is separate from `server.log`, yes... But what do you mean "version above 2"? That's the current, and highest version of Kafka